# Selenium's JavascriptExecutor is not working in JSR223 sampler in JMeter

Tags: javascript, selenium, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I want to measure performance of a Web page in real time. So, got the 1st option of JMeter with Selenium.

I am able to do some navigations and click operations using JSR223 sampler in Java.

But, while waiting for all the JQuery and DOM ready state, I am failed to do in Javascript Executor(org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor). Below is my code of Wait statements.

```
setStrictJava(false); 
/*
---some block of code---
*/
while(true){ 
     Boolean isAjaxCompletes = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0;"); 
     Boolean isJsLoaded = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState;").toString().equals("complete"); 
     if(isAjaxCompletes && isJsLoaded){ 
           break; 
     } 
}
```

I am getting the below error:

```
2018-04-02 18:39:33,794 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.Platform; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; impor . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Static method executeScript( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor' : at Line: 36 :  
 in file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.Platform; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; impor . . . '' : JavascriptExecutor .executeScript ( "return jQuery.active == 0;" ) 
in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.Platform; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; impor . . . '' at line number 36
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.Platform; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; impor . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Static method executeScript( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor' : at Line: 36 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.Platform; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; impor . . . '' : JavascriptExecutor .executeScript ( "return jQuery.active == 0;" ) 
in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.Platform; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; impor . . . '' at line number 36
at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:93) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:69) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
```

Kindly help me to solve this.

JMeter version: 4.0
Plugins auto downloaded selenium version: 2.52.0
Java: 1.8, update 151

Comment: Yes, I added already.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method with static reference which isn't exists. you should create [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) object and call `executeScript` method:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
Boolean isJsLoaded = js.executeScript("return document.readyState;").toString().equals("complete");
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I already tried this one. In this case, below is the error:

`Error in method invocation: Method executeScript( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver'`

But, as you observe in above error mentioned in question, the import statement referred is `Error in method invocation: Static method executeScript( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor'`.

The import statement which is referred is wrong one. This what makes me struggling. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: try `js.executeScript("return document.readyState;", new Object[] {})`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the method `equals()` as follows :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

Boolean isAjaxCompletes = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) webdriver).executeScript("return jQuery.active").equals("0")); 
Boolean isJsLoaded = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The same error only getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all switch to [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language, [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. Second, you can use normal [ExplicitWait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) in the WebDriver Sampler as follows:

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait

   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
   WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5)

   ExpectedCondition<Boolean> documentReady = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
       @Override
       public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
           return WDS.browser.executeScript("return document.readyState")
                   .toString().equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETE");
       }
   };
   wait.until(documentReady)
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
   ```